# React Add Css to Component without addon library

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react component. In this case its a component called Header.js.

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";

export class Header extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (

            <div>   
                <h1>Header Component</h1>
            </div>

        );

    }

}
```

What I need to do now is to add some css to the same component file so inside the js.

I need to do this without using addon libraries like jss etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `css` by following ways:

**1.** Directly with `HTML` element:

```
import React from "react";
export class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{fontSize: '10px'}}>   
                <h1>Header Component</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**2.** You can define the `css object` in the starting of the file then use those `object` in style attribute:

```
let style = {
   a: {fontSize: '10px'}
};

import React from "react";
export class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <div style={style.a}>   
                <h1>Header Component</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Note**: 2nd way is a better way, because it will help you to maintain the code, it makes code clean, compact, more readable and easily maintainable.

Comment: Is it possible to include :hover etc without adding any addons/libraries? If not, I hope react includes it in the future :)

Comment: in these above ways, directly `hover` will not work. For that you need to use `classes`. Assign `class` to any `html` element, then define that `class` in `index.html` file or in external `css` file, there you can define `onhover`, and it will work :)

Comment: Do you know if the React developers are thinking on extending this functionality in react core?

Comment: @dj2017 sorry, no idea about that.